# How to selectively unpack items using @pytest.mark.parametrize?

Tags: python, pytest

```
test_data = [(a1,b1,c1), (a2,b2,c2),..., (an,bn,cn)]
```

For test 1, I would like to unpack them all:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, c", test_data)
```

For test 2, I would like to unpack only a subset, for instance, b and c:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("b, c", test_data)
```

Python will error if I wrote code like above, but is there a way to do so?

Comment: Use a list comprehension to get two-value tuples.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn’t. But you could filter the list of tuples pretty easily:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "b, c",
    [(b, c) for a, b, c in test_data],
)
def test_something(b, c):
    pass
```

Comment: That wasn’t really my point. I meant that you can set up parametrization however you want. The only limit is python syntax. The arguments to parametrize do have to match the function arguments, but it’s up to you how you want to define the thing you’re iterating over.